# why my app is not getting deployed on azure

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I am trying to deploy reactjs app on azure but getting an error.

> Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.

I tried to use wss for a secure connection and also downgraded react-scripts to 3.2.0 but still, I am getting the same error. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please put your codes behind your question and explain more about what step you went and what did it before.

Answer (score 0):

For folks who end up here from Google, while waiting for a patch you can manually edit node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js to fix this problem without downgrading to 3.2. Here's the code you'll want at line 62 of that file:

`protocol: window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss' : 'ws',`

I hope this helps